# Azure Function timer trigger not firing

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I recently changed my Azure Functions project to have `.Net 6 Isolated` runtime, but now when I deploy it my timer triggers are never firing. I've browsed through as many similar posts but nothing I've changed has seem to fix it. It runs fine locally, just not once it's deployed.

#### Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

#### Function's File

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyProj.AzureFunctions
{
    public class Functions
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Functions(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Functions>();
        }

        [Function("Health")]
        public void Health([TimerTrigger("* * * * *")] MyInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Health Check Successful.");
        }
    }

    public class MyInfo
    {
        public MyScheduleStatus ScheduleStatus { get; set; }

        public bool IsPastDue { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyScheduleStatus
    {
        public DateTime Last { get; set; }

        public DateTime Next { get; set; }

        public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### host.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
  }
}
```

#### .csproj configuration

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

#### Azure Functions Settings

[image: Settings]

I've tried to look at the log files in `/LogFiles/Application/Functions/Host` but couldn't find any clues. The file just has this bit repeating a few hundred times

```
2023-02-28T19:48:29.700 [Information] Host Status: {
  "id": "devfunctions",
  "state": "Running",
  "version": "4.15.2.20177",
  "versionDetails": "4.15.2+28e9550320b13137f4eaf16483ebcdb630699506",
  "platformVersion": "99.0.10.793",
  "instanceId": "de79fd99bf2007cea7cba17a54c929b84f3dafad58d9cd5c0c16eccc0cd59790",
  "computerName": "10-30-3-159",
  "processUptime": 4170653,
  "functionAppContentEditingState": "Unknown"
}
```

but can't find any proof that my function is ever firing.

Comment: If you’re seeing run logs but all the function does is add a log entry, it is possible that the logging isn’t working?

Comment: I suppose that could also be the case, but I have 8 other functions that I haven't included in the example that do various things such as send out emails and add entries to a database, and those stopped happening since my update. So I added the ```Health``` function to debug

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at your code, you seem to have run into the same issue I had a while back.

It seems that the VS template creates a five-element cron statement by default: `* * * * *` whilst you actually need six (`NCRONTAB`) for the function to correctly execute: `* * * * * *` (`{second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day-of-week}`)

It's an odd bug, but you can check out more information on Timmer triggers and possible `NCRONTAB` statements [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=isolated-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp).

Comment: Yea, adding the 6 element cron expression is making it fire. Now I just need to figure out why theres no ```ILogger``` instance getting injected.

Comment: You're going to want to open a new question for the `ILogger` issue. You should stick to one "question" per "question", if that makes sense :-)

Comment: This fixed an issue for me that I have been having for a long time - thank you!

Comment: Man... you just saved my night. Thank you! So frustrating.

Comment: That was precisely my problem... Damn, I've been scratching my head for days over this one...

Thank you so much

Comment: Funnily enough, the 5 segment cron expression works fine in debug, using Visual Studio. It's only when deployed to Azure that it fails to work... (rolls eyes)