# Azure Function App is not firing the Timer Trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Timer Trigger that never seems to fire when deployed. I can get it to run successfully every time locally, but as soon as it is deployed, it never seems to work.

I am using the Consumption (Serverless) plan and I am using a Node App in v4. I deployed via VSCode using the Azure Functions Extension.

I have set the **WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE** to "*GMT Standard Time*" in the configuration settings.

My CRON expression is set to run every hour and is '0 * * * *'. I expect it to run every hour on the hour, except it has never run even if I change this to run every 1 minute.

I've try and run the function inside the portal (using the Code + Test option), but for some reason it gives me a 404 not found and I can't see any logs. I'd love to share the invocation ID, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be running for this to happen!

I've also tried following the steps listed on [this page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Investigating-and-reporting-issues-with-timer-triggered-functions-not-firing), but that hasn't helped. FWIW, I have an httpTrigger in the same Function App that runs perfectly - its just the timer that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between CRON and NCRONTAB. Where the Cron uses 5 characters (* * * * *) for every minute, NCRONTAB used 6 characters (0 * * * * *) for every minute.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I managed to fix this after a lot of head scratching. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75597415/335567) fixed the issue for me. Essentially, services such as Timer Triggered Azure Functions and scheduled Azure WebJobs use NCrontab and require the six-part format. This is six parts instead of the five, so my original expression:

- "0 * * * *" - never fires
- "0 0 * * * *" - this one does

It's a pity because the default VSCode template for a Timer Trigger gives you a 5 part CRON expression which never actually works! Changing it to a 6 part expression fixed the issue for me.